# Developing on Windows 10 64-bit, backwards compatibility with Windows XP 32-bit

Tags: windows, vb6, 32bit-64bit

I'm developing and compiling on a Windows 10 64-bit machine.  We've discovered an issue that seems to be related to machines running 32-bit machines.  If I compile the most current code from a 32-bit machine, the issue goes away.

I'd rather not have to develop on one machine and compile from another if I don't  have to.  I'd rather not set up a VirtualMachine running a 32-bit version of Windows, just to compile, if I don't have to.  So, how are people in the "real world" handling this?  I'm using Visual Basic 6 (I know, I know.  But "Just upgrade to .NET" is not the answer I'm looking for.  I'm working on it.  It will take some time.  A lot of time.).

Comment: Compiling VB6 on a 64bit machine should make no difference whatsoever, the IDE/compiler is 32 bit; thats all it knows.   You will need to identify/describe the issue that you are observing, its far more likely to be a dependency issue on the other machine.

Comment: What's the error you are getting and what code gives you that error/issue?  @AlexK. may be right that the issue is related to a dependency in this code.

Comment: It is also possible that VB6 simply doesn't run properly on Windows 10, and is producing binaries that are corrupt in some way.  It is unlikely that very many people are using that particular combination, so you might just be the first to notice the problem.

Comment: We develop 32-bit VB6 code on 64 bit machines all the time. No known issues I am aware of.